# Как расположить места для ввода рядом с кнопками?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, окно

То есть мой самый главный вопрос: как сделать какое-то расстояние между местами для ввода?
Вот, что у меня есть пока:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот часть моего кода, то есть принцип, по которому я иду:

```
que1 = tk.Label(master=frm_form, text="Answer ")
ans1= tk.Entry(master=frm_form, width=100)
def end1():
    end=tk.Label(master=frm_form, text='True!').grid()
but1=tk.Button(text='check', command=end1).place(x=520, y=40)
que1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="e")
ans1.grid(row=4, column=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Буду рада найти ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `grid` вместо `place` (у вас другие элементы через `grid` размещены, поэтому не понятно зачем вам `place`), и указывайте `master=frm_form` при создании кнопки, чтобы все было в одном и том же фрейме (иначе у вас метки и текстовые поля будут во фрейме, а кнопки отдельно в основном окне снаружи фрейма):

```
but1=tk.Button(master=frm_form, text='check', command=end1)

que1.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="e")
ans1.grid(row=4, column=1)
but1.grid(row=4, column=2)
```

Чтобы увеличить "зазор" между колонками или строками, используйте параметры `padx` (расстояние от границ виджета до границ ячейки по горизонтали) и `pady` (по вертикали) метода `grid`.

Пример:

```
for i in range(4):
    que1 = tk.Label(master=frm_form, text=f"Row {i}")
    ans1= tk.Entry(master=frm_form, width=100)
    but1=tk.Button(master=frm_form, text='check')
    
    que1.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=20)
    ans1.grid(row=i, column=1, pady=20)
    but1.grid(row=i, column=2, pady=20)
```

Результат:
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо! Но все равно не получается сделать расстояние между местами для ввода(. А если ввожу ans1.grid(row=400, column=1), все равно он на том же самом месте

Comment: Дополнил ответ.